# java regex - detection string inside code

Tags: java, regex, string

I need some help.

I want detection string inside code using regex.

here my code:

```
String andy="andy said that anna cannot do that";
String anna="anna say \" i cannot do that\""
String empty="";
```

here my regex:

```
Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"");
```

I no have idea how to my regex ignore `\"` ?
so my result are:

> "andy said that anna cannot do that" "anna say \" ""

Comment: So, you want to fetch the entire string - `anna say \" i cannot do that\"` in one line?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the regex? `matches()`, `find()`, `split()`, or something else? --- Also, if `"[^"]*"` is your regex, then it would be written like this as a Java String literal: `"\"[^\"]*\""`. Is that what you have? --- And finally, you show what your results are, but not what you expect them to be, so how do you expect us to help get it right, when we don't know what right is?

Comment: @Rohit Jain : yes, please.

Comment: @Andreas : i want to finding using pattern, I'm sorry for my pattern, i have edit my post.

Comment: @newbie Posted an answer.

Comment: Please show the rest of your code, because you simply cannot get the result you claim to get from what you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>use this pattern `".*?[^\\]"` instead</s>

---

Update: to capture empty use this pattern `("(?:[^"\\]|\\"|\\)*")`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/310)

Comment: i have edit my post, this pattern not match in String empty.

Comment: What is the purpose of `[^\\]`, given that the input string does not contain any backslash characters? The backslashes you see are escapes for the quotes, so the actual value is `anna say " i cannot do that"`. No backslashes.

Comment: @Andreas, the purpose is for the pattern to not stop at `\"` if it exists and continue to the last `"`, the only draw back was the inability to capture empty strings, fixed with updated pattern.

Comment: You're still missing the point. There are **NO** backslashes in the text!!! Still, your updated regex (which as a Java literal would be `(\"(?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\\"|\\\\)*\")`), is matching on backslashes. The `\"` in the `anna` string literal is an escaped quote character, *not* a backslash character followed by a quote character.